# laravel eloquent model generator without artisan

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have found several model generators:

[pepijnolivier/Eloquent-Model-Generator](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiznt-gmeXSAhWNbZoKHRrZAmQQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpepijnolivier%2FEloquent-Model-Generator&usg=AFQjCNFQKyPOuT39-Lj-JNXz39w9JsI1bA&sig2=y9bGPO-C-pJHXDtXVRDDoA)

[krlove/eloquent-model-generator](https://packagist.org/packages/krlove/eloquent-model-generator)

etc.

However they all seem to rely on artisan.

How can I make use of the libraries without it?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to generate model without artisan?

Comment: Well i can explain how to make a model without Artisan but not with a generator(without artisan)

Comment: So you want to know a way to shoot bullets without gun. Interesting.

Comment: Its not impossible, you can make your own command to generate new models but the whole idea for using a framework is to facilitate the process, not to complicate it. So if you can express why you wanna do that, maybe i can suggest an alternative.

Comment: I have a project that only uses eloquent (without laravel), but would like to use the model generators. I do not think that laravel should be a dependency for it.